# Discord.py Check doesnt seem to apply. Doesnt do anything

Tags: discord.py

I wanted to create a bot with a spam feature, but with the condition that it checks for a stop message every cycle. I have tried looking at other posts but neither of them really helped or worked. The check doesn't seem to do aynthing as if the code doesn't reach it. I tried to spot any of the "checked" messages I put into the code to be displayed in the console, but they are not printed, thus my suspicion.

I get no errors in the console, and typing ' *$stop* ' does nothing. Any Idea why?
Thank you.

```
async def bot_spam(message):
try:
    msg = message.content.split(' ')
    if msg[2] == '1':
        await message.channel.send(f"You will ping {msg[1]}, once.")
    elif msg[2] == '0':
        await message.channel.send("You cant ping 0 times.")
        return
    else:
        await message.channel.send(f"You will ping {msg[1]}, {msg[2]} times.")
    time.sleep(1)
    msgr = int(msg[2])
    global spam
    spam = True
    while spam is True and msgr > 0:
        def check1(msg1: discord.Message):
            print("checked")
            if msg1.content == "$stop":
                return False
            return True

        try:
            if await bot.wait_for('message', check=check1, timeout=1.5):
                print("checked 2")
                await message.channel.send("Stopping.")
                spam = False

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.channel.send(f"{msg[1]}")
            msgr -= 1

    await message.channel.send("Done.")
except IndexError:
    await message.channel.send("Your arguments don't make sense \n It's '$spam @someguy timesyouwantpinged'")
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is a logic issue

```py
        def check1(msg1: discord.Message):
            print("checked")
            if msg1.content == "$stop":
                return False
            return True
```

You are returning `False` when "$stop" is typed, thus the bot keeps waiting for a message until check returns `True`

Comment: Doesn't work regardless I have tried it before. That doesnt seem to be the issue.

Comment: Then you are not specifying what you want properly

Your question asked "I get no errors in the console, and typing ' $stop ' does nothing."

what did you do to fix your problem?

Comment: Above that I stated I want to be able to stop a cycle by checking for a stop message. But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Created a variable that checks for $stop using on_message outside the cycle instead of within it.

```
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
    return
else:
    if message.content == "$stop":
            stop = True
            return
```

...

```
    while stop is False and msgr > 0:
        await message.channel.send(f"{msg[1]}")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        msgr -= 1
    if stop is True:
        await message.channel.send("Stopped.")
    else:
        await message.channel.send("Done.")
```